# Load Image In Container View On ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, containers

I have a question regarding view hierarchy:

I currently have a `HomeViewController` that is loaded into view after a login screen. The `HomeViewController` has a `ContainerView`, which is embedded with a `SubViewController`. This container is initially hidden when the home view is loaded. When I trigger an action (via a `UIButton`) to "unhide" the container, I am trying to have an image load in that `SubViewController` that was rendered in the `HomeViewController` during viewDidLoad.

The problem I am facing is that for whatever reason, I can not seem to have the image display in the `SubViewController`.

**FYI**: The way I am rendering this image is such:

1. Upon the `HomeViewController`'s viewDidLoad, I am taking a screen shot programmatically of a `UIView` that is generated from saved user data. This `UIView` is displayed in the view of the `HomeViewController`.
2. When the user clicks a button, I am unhiding and now showing the `SubViewController`, the view embedded in the `ContainerView`.

I can not seem to get the screen shot image (saved as `imageSS`) to appear in the `SubViewController`.  I have tried to suppress the viewDidLoad method for the `SubViewController` when the `HomeViewController` is loaded, then call the `SubViewController` viewDidLoad when the button is pressed to show it, but no luck there either.

This might be confusing but it should be easy - I am at a loss why I can't get this to work. If anyone can help me out I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Here is the code i am currently trying: this method is in the `HomeViewController.m`

```
- (void)takeScreenshot:(id)sender {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_homeRenderImage.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [_homeRenderImage drawViewHierarchyInRect:_homeRenderImage.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *imageSS = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    SubViewController *pvc = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
    userImage = imageSS;

    [pvc loadImage];

}
```

Here is the method I am using in the `SubViewController.m`:
NOTE: userImage is a shared property between these controllers. I have tested that this sharing works

```
- (void)loadImage {
    _subImage.image = userImage;
}
```

Comment: show us the code related to image

Comment: my b. I re-edited the post to include the code

Comment: i tried to directly set the image in the SubViewController as the image from the screen shot context but that didnt work

Comment: @T_77 also just tried moving the code that i want executed in the SubViewController to a separate method, then calling that upon the button click. that did not work either :\

Comment: are u able to see image data?

Comment: yeah. I made a test UIImageView that loads with the homeview just to make sure it was working and it shows the image just fine. I cant seem to have the ContainerView's SubViewController to display this image

Comment: I'm not sure which screen you'd like to snap in `–viewDidLoad` as the current view is not in the view-hierachy then yet, so the screenshot might be an empty/blank image, according to your sample code of taking a self-shot.

Comment: it seems to be working now - I called the loadImage method in the viewWillAppear method in the SubViewController. i feel kind of silly now that i think about it but at least it works now. thanks for the help tho!

Answer (score 0):

I feel dumb - all I needed to do was to call the loadImage method in the viewWillAppear method:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
    [self loadImage];
}
```